# Можно ли поменять цвет текста в кавычках css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Добрый вечер всем, возник такой вопрос: Можно ли поменять цвет текста в кавычках css? Если можно то как это сделать? Есть форма, у меня есть placeholder, в нём текст, допустим "Ваше имя*" и вот как можно поменять цвет звездочки в этом плейсхолдере на красный цвет? Можно даже варанты с js. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Звездочка, это как я понимаю обязательное поле? Её выносят за input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
```

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
      color: pink;
    }
    input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
      color: pink;
    }
    input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
      color: pink;
    }
    input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
      color: pink;
    }
```